# Fix For Blanked Out UUID On Luks Encrypted Drive?

Tags: linux, encryption, mount, luks, uuid

### Problem:

When I mount a Luks Encrypted drive, the drive mounts, but I can't access the files.

The drive is the root drive.  It has ElementaryOS installed on it.
It booted fine, until after doing some dd & Gparted operations.

Now it unlocks on the boot, but can't find root-data logical volume.

### Symptoms:

The drive when mounted shows no UUID or mount point.

### Thesis:

Somewhere/somehow the UUID got blanked out.  And when mounted, the file system can't attach a UUID to a logical volume.  So no logical volumes show.  And as a result, no mount point.

### Background:

The problem started after partitioning other drives using Gparted.

When I trying to boot afterward, I could mount the boot drive that was encrypted with Luks, but then the boot could not find the root folder.

### Solutions?

Potential?  Mount the drive using terminal.  Then assign a UUID to the mounted drive.  Then somehow attach the logical volumes to the UUID?

...How would I do this?

### What I've tried:

..Too much to tell.  I was going down the wrong direction.  Lets hope ^^^^ is closer to the solution.

### More info:

lsblk -f:  Shows the encrypted drive (sdc2) mounted, with the mapper param I gave cryptsetup luksopen (test11 in this case).

It sdc1 shows the UUID. sdc2 shows no UUID or mount point.

[image]

Comment: To little information/wrong hypothesis/unear problem statement.  What distro/version are you using?  It looks to me like  there is no filesystem on the LUKS partition. (Ie you need to mkfs.ext4 /dev/test111 - of-course this is a destructive process - its not clear if this is a new partition or is aupposed to already have data on it.

Comment: Yeah, it's time to dust off your backups. The LUKS container is fine but filesystem inside it is gone. So either restore it from known good copy or hope that file recovery software can find something.

Comment: Added more details ^^^^.  Problem is it's not finding the file system.  The only difference I can see between a similar encrypted drive that mounts maps to a mount point and the problem drive is the problem drive no long shows a UUID.

Comment: 2nd time this has happened.  Prior, it wiped my data drive.  I was using Gparted and Disks both times to partion/format (I did not do any operations on affected drives).

Comment: hexdump shows decrypted data.  Anyway to extract that data to somewhere I can navigate usable files?

Comment: Make sure the LUKS volume is opened and scan `/dev/mapper/whateverNameWasUsed` with file recovery software.